# Whirlyglobe private API complain during app submission

Tags: ios, iphone, appstore-approval

I have a simple app which uses whirlyglobe framework (2.2). Otherwise, it is pretty basic program with Apple frameworks.

When I tried to validate the app (and during the distribution, Xcode complains that my app is using private API; specifically it calls "rootElement", and "attributeForFont:". I suspect these functions are part of WhilyGlobe component distribution.

What is the easiest way to remove those files from the framework? Do I need to have the source and compile the framework myself? Or is there a simpler way?

[image: xcode error message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Here is what I did:

1) Searched in github repository of WhirlyGlobe and found the file that uses the functions which caused issue.
2) I did not need the functionality provided by the file that had the functions.
3) Removed the references (class instantiation) to the file from my project.

Answer (score 0):

That's actually part of the KissXML framework and the implementation is in there.  I suspect Apple's test is in error.

In any case, if you're not using the WMS functionality, you can probably drop it out just fine.

Comment: Thanks @mousebird. It would be helpful if you can rename those functions for future.

Comment: It's an external library, so that's tricky.  I've got an app submission in process right now.  I'll see if it runs into the same problem.  If it does, I think I'll just make WMS optional instead.